# MVC PRG pattern conflict with SessionState

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, viewdata, tempdata, stateserver

I've an MVC3 web app. In that I've been using the **PRG** (Post-Redirect-Get) pattern. That is during postback if any model validation fails I [persist the ViewData in TempData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279665/how-can-i-maintain-modelstate-with-redirecttoaction) and then redirect to the original GET action.

In post action -

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    TempData["ViewData"] = ViewData;
```

Later in the GET action -

```
if (TempData["ViewData"] != null)
    ViewData = (ViewDataDictionary)TempData["ViewData"];
```

This is pretty much the usual practice. Everything has been working fine till date. **Now**, we need to improve session persistence that is we need "longer" sessions. I've concluded to use [ASP.Net State Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779041/asp-net-mvc-keep-session-alive-for-as-long-as-possible).

After I migrated my session to State Server -

```
web.config - 
<system.web> ... 
<sessionState timeout="180" mode="StateServer" cookieless="UseCookies" />  
...
```

I started getting "unable to serialize" errors for some of my sessions which stored custom objects. I've made such objects **[Serializable]** which sorted out the issue. But now I'm stuck with the above PRG pattern!

> **Error** - Type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary' in Assembly
>   'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.

Strange I'm not able to find a single thread which share my scenario. Any one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that [TempData is stored in session](http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/07/asp-net-mvc-do-you-know-where-your-tempdata-is/) and my session is in turn stored in external process demands that anything being stored must be "Serializable".

Objects like ViewDataDictionary or even ModelStateDictionary are NOT [Serializable]. For MVC PRG I just need to pass the modelstate errors and the invalid object.

> I've already marked the object as [Serializable] (I'm using xml
>   serializer to "stringify" my obj and then store it - because its a L2S
>   Entity so need to avoid circular refs as well). Ref [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434534/serialize-an-object-to-string)

```
TempDate["modelToPass"] = Serialization.Serialize<MyModel>(modelToPass);
```

And likewise I can translate my ModelState object (only for the errors) into a "simpler" object and transform it into something like

```
KeyValuePair<string,List<string>>[]
```

In short, I'm trying to make my modelstate and modelObject "serializable" so that I can put them in TempData and persist the PRG pattern.

There're some other approaches to deploy our own TempData and store TempData in cookies, etc.. but I don't want to complicate things. Do let me know if anyone has a better solution to this.

Some Ref urls

- [Can't serialize ModelState](http://forums.asp.net/t/1651072.aspx/1)
- [Cookie based TempDate](http://afana.me/post/session-less-controllers-and-TempData-ASPNET-MVC.aspx)
- [Adv usage for json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845852/asp-net-mvc-how-to-convert-modelstate-errors-to-json)
- AJAX + PRG [one](http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/automatic-modelstate-validation-in-aspnet-mvc), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845852/asp-net-mvc-how-to-convert-modelstate-errors-to-json)